# How can i set my rectangle to retain its size while bouncing in the canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas

The problem is i want to retain the size of my rectangle while its moving back and forth within the canvas. This is myview.java code:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private int xMin = 0;
    private int xMax;
    private int yMin = 0;
    private int yMax;
    private float rectX =130;
    private float rectY =180;
    private float rectSpeedX = 5;
    private float rectSpeedY = 3;
    private RectF RectBounds;
    private Paint paint;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        RectBounds = new RectF();
        paint = new Paint();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        RectBounds.set(rectX, rectX, rectY, rectY);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(RectBounds,paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(RectBounds,paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(RectBounds,paint);
        start();
        invalidate();
    }
    private void start() {
        rectX += rectSpeedX;
        rectY += rectSpeedY;
        if (rectX> xMax) {
            rectSpeedX = -rectSpeedX;
            rectX = xMax;
        } else if (rectX < xMin) {
            rectSpeedX = -rectSpeedX;
            rectX = xMin;
        }
        if (rectY > yMax) {
            rectSpeedY = -rectSpeedY;
            rectY = yMax;
        } else if (rectY  < yMin) {
            rectSpeedY = -rectSpeedY;
            rectY = yMin;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        xMax = w-1;
        yMax = h-1;
    }
}
```

Also if you have any suggestion to make my codes shorter. I'll be glad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that:

```
RectBounds.set(rectX, rectX + rectWidth, rectY, rectY + rectHeight);
```

also you should use no capital letter for object names (RectBounds -> rectBounds) or for this specific case you should just name it 'rect' because it IS a RectF.

Comment: Okay i use "RectBounds.set(rectX, rectX + rectWidth, rectY, rectY + rectHeight);" What will i change in the start method?

Comment: You have to change the border detection for bottom and right because your rect got a width and height. Also you have to define at the top two new variables: 
private int rectWidth = anynumber; and 
private int rectHeight = anynumber;

Comment: I think my void start is mess up because the rectangle is moving while changing shapes LoL